# Regex is pegging cpu

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have 4 regex that I got spun up and they work great but on some applications they are pegging out the cpu.  I know they are quite the best looking regex but I am not sure of a better way.  Is there some things I can do to optimize these regex?

```
public static Regex schemaOrg = new Regex(@"\s*itemtype\s*=\s*('|"")\s*http://schema.org/\s*", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static Regex dataVocabulary = new Regex(@"\s*itemtype\s*=\s*('|"")\s*http://data-vocabulary.org/\s*", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Basically looking for:

```
itemtype="http://schema.org/"
```

```
itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/"
```

But with any amount of spaces since that would still be valid in html.

For example:

```
itemtype   ="http://schema.org/"
```

```
itemtype=   "http://schema.org/"
```

```
itemtype="   http://schema.org/   "
```

Would all be valid.

UPDATED: Still wraps up the cpu bad.

```
\s+itemtype\s*=\s*(?:'|"")\s*http://schema\.org/
```

Comment: Are you missing a closing `('|"")` at the end?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: If anything, it should be a closing `\1`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Of course it *should* (and in an answer it *would*), but in a comment asking if the OP has forgotten about the trailing quote `('|"")` is easier to understand than a backreference.

Comment: Sorry for slow responses I am trying suggestions below and I am not checking the trailing quotes do to there could be more that comes after so like .org/LocalBusiness which I only care about up to the .org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of a few things so far.

- The trailing `\s*` (in `schema.org/\s*` and `vocabulary.org/\s*`) isn't required, remove it. I assumed this because you are not checking for a trailing quote either.
- `. (dot)` has a special meaning in regex, escape it like so `\.` in `schema.org` and `data-vocabulary.org`.
- The first `\s*` doesn't make sense as it will also match your pattern with `someitemtype`. Either replace it with `\s+` or try using a word boundary `\b` for the start of pattern.
- If you are paranoid about it you can also prevent Regex from capturing the group `('|"")` by replacing it with `(?:'|"")`.

**EDIT :** You can also try lazy matching and see if it helps. I can imagine a case where your regex will choke up the CPU. Try the sample regex below:

```
\s+?itemtype\s*?=\s*?(?:'|"")\s*?http://schema\.org/
```

If this does not help please post the code and sample string in the context of this problem.

Comment: You said it. `.` (dot) is like an ant in convoluted regular expressions and very easy to miss when part of a URL regex.

Comment: This is still hanging the cpu terribly.  Did I miss any changes. In OP.

Comment: Try the edit and (please) implement it for both regex patterns before posting the results. I am hoping it would help.

Comment: Sorry! Added the `\s+?` in a later edit.
The sample string taking time could help too.

Comment: @TanzeelKazi I have the other regex commented out in the code so that it is not affected anything and I am just using the one under your EDIT comment (the newest one) and its still choking. I am scanning the source of a site for this string so its going through html if that helps any.

Comment: Could you point us to the site or put up the sample source somewhere like in pastebin or jsfiddle?

Comment: It is an seo spider and running it against ask.com

Comment: @Adam: If it is a text processing app, why do you expect text processing to not be the most expensive part of the application?

Comment: @leppie we do a lot of analyzing and its expensive but should not peg the cpu.  We cannot figure out why these two in particular cause it to sky rocket.

Comment: @leppie I am curious too as to the amount of data being processed but without sample data and the code being executed it's tough to come to a conclusion on it.

Comment: These were all helpful ideas but ended up moving it all to html agility pack do to the regex was still pegging the cpu even after the modifications.  I have noted all these tips for future regex.

Answer (score 0):

a possible improvement is:

replace all " " to "" before doing regex.match

then your regex does not need all these \s